# Bash Script fails when executing against docker container

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, docker

What I need to do: create a MongoDB 3 way replica set and automate it with a bash script. When I do it manually it works just fine but my script doesn't.

The script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Updating the system, this might take a couple minutes..."
sudo yum -y update

echo "Installing Docker"
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

echo "Starting Services"
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker

echo "Creating Network..."
sudo docker network create mongo-cluster

echo "Creating 3 MongoDB Instances"

sudo docker run -p 30001:27017 --name primary --net mongo-cluster mongo 
mongod --replSet comments && sudo docker start primary

sudo docker run -p 30002:27017 --name failover1 --net mongo-cluster mongo 
mongod --replSet comments && sudo docker start failover1

sudo docker run -p 30003:27017 --name failover2 --net mongo-cluster mongo 
mongod --replSet comments && sudo docker start failover2

docker exec -it primary bash -c "echo 'db = (new 
Mongo(\"localhost:27017\")).getDB(\"test\")' | mongo && echo 'config = 
{\"_id\": \"comments\",\"members\": [{\"_id\": 0,\"host\": 
\"primary:27017\"},{\"_id\": 1,\"host\":\"failover1:27017\"},{\"_id\": 
2,\"host\": \"failover2:27017\"}]}' | mongo && echo 'rs.initiate(config)' | 
mongo"

echo "Completed!"
```

From this I get this output :

> **MongoDB server version: 4.0.0 2018-07-29T14:32:58.666+0000 E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: config is not defined : @(shell):1:1**

Which is the very last command failing because it can't find any config there. It seems like the last 3 commands are being executed separately, hence when trying to execute the last piece it fails. I tried removing the last command and script works flawlessly, BUT, once I login to the mongo instance and run the last command manually, nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ps. im a newbie, dont hate me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to do this:

```
echo "Creating Network..."
sudo docker network create mongo-cluster

echo "Creating 3 MongoDB Instances"

sudo docker run -d -p 30001:27017 --name primary --net mongo-cluster mongo mongod --replSet comments && sudo docker start primary

sudo docker run -d -p 30002:27017 --name failover1 --net mongo-cluster mongo mongod --replSet comments && sudo docker start failover1

sudo docker run -d -p 30003:27017 --name failover2 --net mongo-cluster mongo mongod --replSet comments && sudo docker start failover2
sleep 5 #let the quorum happens
sudo docker exec -it primary bash -c "echo 'config = {\"_id\": \"comments\",\"members\": [{\"_id\": 0,\"host\":\"primary:27017\"},{\"_id\": 1,\"host\":\"failover1:27017\"},{\"_id\":2,\"host\": \"failover2:27017\"}]};rs.initiate(config)' | mongo"

echo "Completed!"
```

Problems:

1. You are running mongod command in separate line from docker run
2. You are running docker run without -d (detached mode)
3. You are piping config to another mongo shell session and expecting it to be there. what I changed is that I removed unecessary pipes and replaced them with ";".